# Computer connects OK to the network, but applications won't access internet

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, configuration

Here is the scenario: The computer connects to my network, the DHCP server asigns to it an IP address, and sets every thing right. I can ping, trace and it resolves DNS.

Here is the problem: I can`t get any application to access the internet (e.g.: IE, Firefox), and when working with another computer each time I do a ping to it, I get a request time out message. I tried tracing the computer through my network and I'm getting the same result.

Computer's Operating System: Windows Vista Starter Edition.
Network: Connecting through a wireless router or connecting an UTP cable to it (Doesn't matter I get the same exact result).
DHCP Server: It is set up to wrok with a maximum of 20 connections. At the moment there are less than 5 computers connected to the network.
Firewall: Within my network there are no firewalls working.
Router restrictions: I didn't set my router to restrict access (e.g. Mac address restriction).

So far, all I can think of is that it's a problem with the operating system. It seems to me that the network connection works fine.

**Here is some update**: I found out when this started, just after removing Symantec's Live Update. Still not knowing how to resolve it. Apparently, Norton's desintallation tool, messes with the dns configuration. I found a work around that worked, but I still couldn't find the real reason of my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You say "I can ping, trace" but it is not clearWHAT. The host itself? The router? Any destination on the Internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there are still some parts of  the Symantec security software you removed. Try to download and run the [Norton Removal Tool](http://service1.symantec.com/Support/tsgeninfo.nsf/docid/2005033108162039).

If your Internet connectivity is not back after running the cleanup tool and restarting the computer, try to fix Winsock.  Open a command prompt (Start > Run > type `cmd`) and enter this command:

```
 netsh winsock reset
```

Restart your PC after entering the command and try to open a public web page.

Comment: I've downloaded the Norton Removal Tool and it worked. My problem has been solved.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you temporary disable the windows firewall?

Comment: +1 my answer also.  It the apps work with the firewall disabled, enable it and open the appropriate port.

Comment: The firewall is turned off. The whole scenario is with no firewall working on the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Can you ping your router from the machine? Is the IP address you see on the PC in the range of addresses your DHCP assigns, for example 192.168.0.x - 192.168.0.y? Or maybe there are some firewall settings on your router prohibiting access, if not explicitly set for a new machine.

There is no restriction in Windows Vista Starter edition which disables internet access. There are only some other network features disabled as described in this Microsoft Help article: [Networking in Windows Vista Starter](http://windowshelp.microsoft.com/Windows/en-US/Help/44526469-b916-4442-9372-4f566795bbcf1033.mspx).

Comment: Splattne, I can ping every computer in the network, the router and even I can ping ServerFault. What confuses me is that when I ping from every other computer to this particular one, I get a Time out message.

Comment: Firewall issue on that PC? Did you try to temporarily turn it off?